Integration Testing of a windows forms project in Visual Studio 2022 that uses Firestore for database
I have a question, is there a way to do integration testing of my Windows Forms application if I use Firestore for my database inside of Visual Studio 2022.
I need this for my project and I'm just wondering, is it even possible to create fake Firestore objects using libraries like I FakeItEasy.
And another question, can I and should I use the emulator?
If yes, is there some way I can use the emulator inside of Visual Studio 2022 or can I somehow start the emulator in Visual Studio Code and do the xUnit tests inside of Visual Studio 2022 like I'm supposed to do.
I could use some help because I haven't found any useful links to help me with these questions.
Also I'm using google.cloud.firestoreV1 NuGet package and everything that comes with it for managing the work I do on my database
